# Portability of files without file extension?

Tags: java, filesystems, nio

Traditionally file extensions are just a convention on Unix-like operating systems. It seems that nowadays NTFS is also able to store files without file extension and Microsoft Windows handle them. Is there guarantee that conforming implementations must be able to handle file without file extension in Java's NIO API or is this dependent on the file system provider?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question correctly but file extensions are not required by Java's NIO etc. You'd need them to get a hint on the format they should represent - if you don't know that anyways - otherwise you'd have to scan the file and hope for some header/content/whatever that let's you identify what the file represents.

Comment: Conforming implementations of what? What do you mean by "Microsoft Windows handle them"? You've *always* been able to write files without an extension, in every platform I've ever used...

Comment: @Thomas I want to know whether I can safely create files without file extension.

Comment: @JonSkeet Conforming to the specification that defines Java NIO or other aspects of Java SE.

Comment: Well I would expect it to be platform-specific... if you were *really* on a platform (OS, file system, whatever) that didn't support filenames without extensions, it would be bizarre to require that. But it would be equally bizarre *not* to support it when the platform does. I've never seen a platform that *wouldn't* support this...

Comment: @JonSkeet I have never seen such platform as well, even z/OS and IBM i have file systems that can handle files without file extensions. But on the other hand I don't program against a particular platform.

Comment: In that case I'd just go about it since all major platforms should support files without extensions. If there's an exotic platform that doesn't chances are there's not even a JVM for it.